# Ruby: Delete from an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to delete specific rows from an array of arrays. The data looks like this:

```
[
  ["Name1", "Email1", "Type1"],
  ["Name1", "Email1", "Type2"],
  ["Name1", "Email1", "Type3"],
  ["Name2", "Email2", "Type3"],
  ["Name2", "Email2", "Type4"]
]
```

If the type is e.g. "Type1" or "Type2" then all remaining rows with the same username should be removed. If the type is not e.g. "Type1" or "Type2", the lines should stay in the array. This means, the resulting array should look like this:

```
[
  ["Name1", "Email1", "Type1"],
  ["Name2", "Email2", "Type3"],
  ["Name2", "Email2", "Type4"]
]
```

The array is sorted by the username before I loop through the array. The coding I'm currently using is this one:

```
inputfile_content.each.with_index do |inputrow, index|
  if (index + 1) != inputfile_content.length
    if inputrow[0] == inputfile_content[(index + 1)][0]
      if ["Type1", "Type2"].include?(inputrow[2])
        inputfile_content.delete_at(index + 1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But obviously it's not fully working, it only removes the next entry in the array but not all occurrences of the same username. Anyone any clue how to fix this? A nested inputfile_content.each or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: What is a row? What is a line? What is `type`? What is `username`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Is there a difference between a line and a row and does this anyhow belong to the question I've asked? The same applies to the type and the username.

Anyhow, the answer was quite simple:

`while inputrow[0] == inputfile_content[(index + 1)][0]
  inputfile_content.delete_at(index + 1)
end`

Comment: "Is there a difference between a line and a row" -- That's part of the question I am asking you. And the same applies to the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Solved with a loop instead of a single delete:

```
while inputrow[0] == inputfile_content[(index + 1)][0]
  inputfile_content.delete_at(index + 1)
end
```

Comment: You have not made clear, but I am assuming that `inputfile_content` is the array you have shown. Not sure if your answer works or not for your particular example, if it does it is just coincidence. First, as `index` reaches the last one, `inputfile_content[(index + 1)]` will become `nil`, and calling `[0]` on it will raise an error. Second, calling `delete_at` during iteration is generally wrong.

Comment: Sure, ìnputfile_content` is the array of arrays, ìnputrow` is, I thought this was obvious, only a single array. Concerning the `nil` situation, take a look at the original loop, the end of loop situation is already covered by `if (index + 1) != inputfile_content.length`. Therefore you will never have the situation that `[0]` is `nil`. Furthermore I don't understand why I shouldn't use `delete_by` in a loop, what would be a better approach? The array of arrays in the input file is dynamically generated and I can not predict how much lines per username need to be deleted.